# How to retrieve BCC from a number seed?

Tags: bitcoin-cash

I put BTC on the coolwallet card and now I cannot access my BCC. Does anyone know how to access funds with a number seed? It states on the coolwallet website that if you have word seeds you can access BCC but if you have number seeds you're out of luck and you'll have to wait until gods knows when.

I cannot find any information on number seeds so if anyone can give some input on this it would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "number seed"? What does it look like and what do you use it for?

Comment: Number seeds are numbers used instead of words for seeds. So instead of 12 random words you have 12 randome sets of numbers. Dont use coolwallet, its a hard wallet and it stinks, trezor or ledger and every other wallet i have used, uses words for seeds but not coolwallet and i cannot access my keys, very frustrating.